# How to run TypeScript programs in Android?

Tags: android, typescript, termux

How can I run TypeScript programs using a Android phone? Are there any apps available to run TypeScript programs offline on Android?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can run TypeScript programs on Android using Termux.
Follow these steps to run TypeScript in Termux.

1. Download and install official [**Termux**](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Installing_from_F-Droid) from F-Droid Repository.
2. Install *Node.js* package in termux using the command `pkg install nodejs`
3. Install TypeScript node module on Termux using command `npm install typescript`
4. Install code editor like Micro using command `pkg install micro`.
   You can also use any code editor apps like [**Acode**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.foxdebug.acodefree) or [**Spck**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.spck).
5. Create a TypeScript file using command `micro hello.ts`
   This will open a editor where you can write your TypeScript code. If you are writing the program using external code editor apps, change the working directory of Termux to the folder where you have saved your TypeScript program.
6. After writing TypeScript code, come back to terminal and type `tsc hello.ts` this will compile your TypeScript to JavaScript and create **hello.js** file in the same directory.
7. Now you can run the JavaScript file using command `node hello.js` and it will show output of the code.

For shortcut, you can combine step 6 & 7 commands and use it like `tsc hello.ts && node hello.js`

Answer (score 1):

Also when you install **termux** try use **f-droid** package manager to install termux instead of using **Google play store** as follows https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Installing_from_F-Droid

Comment: Maybe add "why" you think they should do this?

Answer (score 0):

You must install Termux from F-droid since the Google Play Store version is outdated and will be removed soon, the creators are still working on termux on GitHub

Answer (score 0):

There is a step 8 to be added to the answer by Bibek Oli as `tsc` is not in the default path:

Either add `~/node_modules/typescript/bin/` to $PATH or put a shell function `tsc() { ~/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc "$@" ; }` to .bash_profile